# Alpine JS using wrong id

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm currently making a data table with Laravel Livewire and I use AlphineJS for the confirmation modal. Everything works fine until I paginate to the next page of the data. So here HTML for my delete button for each row :

```
    <a class="mx-1 text-lg" role="button" x-on:click.prevent="onDelete({{ $article->id }})">
       <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
       <p x-text="{{ $article->id }}"></p>
    </a>
```

Here s function for onDelete

```
    onDelete(id){
      console.log(id);
      this.confirmationModal = true;
      this.id = id;
    },
```

This is what happens when I try to delete article with an ID of 36, it will console.log the id of the article which is 36
[image: Before Navigation]

Then I navigate to the next page and try to delete the article with an ID of 46 but the console.log remains 36, I was expecting 46
[image: After Navigation]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change x-on:click to wire:click

```
<a class="mx-1 text-lg" role="button" wire:click="$emit('onTrashIcon',{{ $article->id }})">
   <i class=" fas fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

and add listener function x-data + don't forget to x-init="listen()"

```
    listen() {
      window.livewire.on('onTrashIcon', articleId => {
        this.id = articleId;
        this.confirmationModal = true;
      })
    }
```